# Coredata unable to delete the existing record + multithreading

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am parsing xml , inserting an entity in the database, for updating record I am again adding that record and deleting the older record. But it is not able to delete the older entry so I am able to see duplicate entries.

```
- (void)insertSampleWithId:(NSString *)sampleId{

    __block NSError *lError = nil;

    dispatch_queue_t categoryCustomQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.xyz.sample”, NULL);

    dispatch_sync(categoryCustomQueue, ^{

        NSNotificationCenter *dnc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

        [dnc addObserver:self
                selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
                    name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                  object:_tempMOC];


        _supplier = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"BSSample” inManagedObjectContext:_tempMOC];
        _supplier.sampleId = supplierId;

//        double delayInSeconds = 0.3;
//        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
//        
//        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
//            
       // });

        [self ifSupplierPresentInMainContextRemoveIt:supplierId];

        if(![_tempMOC save:&lError]){

            NSLog(@"Error adding while category %@ ,%@ ,%@", lError, [lError userInfo], [lError localizedDescription]);
        }

        [dnc removeObserver:self name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:_tempMOC];

    });

}


- (BOOL)ifSamplePresentInMainContextRemoveIt:(NSString *)sampleId{

    __block BSSampler *suppl = nil;

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext  = dataManager.coreDataHelper.context;

    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                              entityForName:@"BSSample” inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];


    [_fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];

    [_fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"sampleId == '%@'", supplierId]];
    [_fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

    [_fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *array = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:_fetchRequest error:&error];


    if(array != nil && [array count]>0){
        suppl = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    if(suppl)
    [dataManager.coreDataHelper.context deleteObject:suppl];
    return [dataManager.coreDataHelper.context save:&error];

}

- (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)saveNotification{

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeToMainThred:) withObject:saveNotification waitUntilDone:NO];
}


- (void)mergeToMainThred:(NSNotification*)saveNotification{

    [dataManager.coreDataHelper.context mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:saveNotification];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no code here that shows your delete.

You say that are not able to delete but you don't say why or how. What is failing?  What is your expectation and what is the actual results?

What does `mergeChanges:` look like?

Please update your question so that we have a chance of understanding the issue.